# Routing DHCP into different LANS

Tags: routing, dhcp

If I had a router that's connects my 2 LANs and there is a single DHCP, in the either LAN. How and what would be my configurations for the DHCP so that it provides the IPs to both the LANS through the router.

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need on your router a feature called `DHCP relay`

You configure it with the IP address of your DHCP server.
When the router receive a DHCP request it will send (as unicast) a request to the DHCP server containing the MAC address of the original requester and the network address of the interface on which it received the request. 
The network address allow the DHCP server to pick the correct scope.

Then the DHCP server makes a DHCP offer for an IP address in the appropriate network and send it back to the router which forward it to the requestor.

Comment: Don't forget that the DHCP server needs to support remote subnets as well. Simple ones don't.

Comment: while the question is only pertaining to DHCP, I think it's interesting to note that this relay/forwarding feature is not unique to DHCP. Most vendors will have some way to forward other UDP protocols as well. DNS relay is another very common feature that is encountered a lot.

Answer (score 0):

On router and switches its called "ip-helper".

Cisco, HP and some more